# Use USB numeric keypad with phone-like typing?

Tags: linux, keyboard, udev

I have USB numeric keypad like this:

[image]

I need to write chars (A to Z) on this keyboard, and so my idea is to use it like on old cell phone:

[image]

If I press 1x 2 it writes A, 2x 2 - B, 4x 9 - Z, etc.

Is possible to do it? And how? Using udev?

Comment: I want to know the purpose of doing this.

Comment: It would allow full (-ish) text entry on a rather small keyboard, potentially useful for small/embedded systems. I'd be curious if anyone's developed anything.

Comment: Purpose is for example in embedded system. Why old cell phones do not have full-qwerty keyboard?

Comment: Take a look at [this solution on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12078199/1768141)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is use **multipress** input method.

In app is need to set multipress input method manually. If you want have multipress as default you need to create file `/.xinputrc` with content:

```
GTK_IM_MODULE=multipress
QT_IM_MODULE=multipress
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a full answer, but here are some things that may help.

If your keypad is hooked up to a computer with a gui desktop based on Gnome or KDE, [AutoKey](https://code.google.com/p/autokey/) can be used to turn the keys into hotkeys which can do almost anything you can think of. Since key presses on the pad are probably indistinguishable from the corresponding keys on your regular keyboard, anything you do will affect them as well.

Run `xev` from a terminal and press each key on the pad to see what keycodes are generated. They're probably the same as those for a normal keyboard, but if not, you can use those codes to differentiate the two.

If you are on an embedded system (or even a server) with no gui, the above won't work.

I'm not very versed in Linux devices, but [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/read-keyboard-status-not-wait-for-keyboard-input-888869/) post may give you a clue as to how to process keyboard input directly into a script or program. Once you get the key presses into the script, you can do whatever you like in response to them.

Since this is a script/program, you'd have to figure out a way to get its output to the desired destination.

The first approach that comes to mind is using a pipe. That will work if the output is only going to one program.

If the solution needs to be a bit more general, a named pipe may work. I haven't had to use those yet, so I'm a bit sketchy on how you would use the same named pipe serially connected to different programs.